# How replace only the next word after search string?

Tags: sql, replace, find

how can i find and replace only the next word after a search string with a select statement?

For example:

"The user Mr Smith helped me a lot" --> Output: "The user Mr X helped me a lot"

The search string is "Mr" and there a many different last names (data protection reasons).

Thank you :)

Comment: is it t-sql or mysql?

Comment: sorry, it´s t-SQL (MSSQL)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are asking the correct question.
with your "replace next word" you will run into issues.
By the looks of your example, this is a free text input from an end user (assuming VARCHAR(MAX)) and it is hard to predict what variation end users could type. 
you could therefore have search items;
   - Mr Smith

- Mr. Smith
- Mister Smith
- Mistar Smith (spelling error intentional for example)
- Mrs Smith
- Miss Smith
- Mr & Mrs Smith (2 people)
- Mr. + Mrs & Miss Smith (Family of 3 with the end users using/not using punctuation and using different AND symbols)
- Mrs&MrSmith (End user didn't want Spaces for the entity)
- Dr. Smith (or Doc or Doc. or Doct or Doct. or Doctor or misspelled Docter)
- Prof. Smith (Pro. or Professor or Proffessor or Profeser or Pr)
- Father Smith (Ftr.)
- Rev Smith (rev
- Earl Smith
- Sir Smith
- Dame Smith
- Lady Smith
- Chancellor Smith
- etc. (Note: these are just English titles, what if there is a German Herr, a French Monsieur or a title from any other language in the text?)

Also you have the issue of "the next word", what about double barrel names, names that are broken by hyphens or even those containing apostrophes (e.g. Mr Smith Carroll / Mr Smith-Carroll / Mr O'Carroll)?
At what point do you want the next word to finish? The next space? The next non-surname? Do you have a list of all surnames to check this against?

You really need to encrypt the db to be 100% sure that no data will accidentally not be replaced.
Make it protocol going forward not to allow the use of actual names in free text boxes, i.e. have the end users type "Mr X" in the text box from now on, but encryption seems to be your best/safest option.

Answer (score 0):

Use **STUFF()** Function of MSSQL. [STUFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_stuff.asp)

Comment: Use **CHARINDEX()** to find the index of **Mr** or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a query which would help you to extract the required result. 
Note:- I am using '*addressstreet*' as a column which you can replace with **your column** and *Box* with **Mr**.

```
 WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT  SUBSTRING(addressstreet ,1,(CHARINDEX(' BOX ',addressstreet  + ' ')-1))TEST0,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([addressstreet], CHARINDEX('BOX ', [addressstreet]), LEN([addressstreet])),'BOX','')test, addressstreet FROM [dbo].[Vendor]
  where addressstreet like '% BOX %')
  ,CTE2 AS(
  SELECT TEST0, ltrim(stuff(TEST,1,charindex(' ',TEST),''))TEST1, ADDRESSSTREET  FROM CTE
  )

  SELECT TEST0 + ' Mr X '+ ltrim(stuff(TEST1,1,charindex(' ',TEST1),'')) RequiredOutput, ADDRESSSTREET from cte2
```

This SQL statement is not a performance optimum query, but you can achieve your objective.

Output:-

```
RequiredOutput                          AddressStreet
P.O. Mr X Street Plaza                  P.O. BOX 32109 Street Plaza
```